# Implementing oAuth with DNN

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth, dotnetnuke

I have to implement oAuth with DNN. How should i proceed? Should I use the existing oAuth libraries and just create a new provider for oAuth authentication or should i proceed otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oliver Hine created one already - you can use it as a base - http://dnntwitter.codeplex.com/